# Best practice fetching users keycloak

Tags: python, vue.js, openid-connect, keycloak

I really don't know what is the best practice fetching users with keycloak in an frotend application. I'm currently building an Vue.js frontend application which works with the keycloak.js lib. I also have a backend written in Python.

Do I need to fetch users first by my backend and afterwards fetch them on the frontend? Or otherwise fetch them directly on the frontend.

What should you do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no best practice in such a task. It depends on what kind of business logic you need. If you just need to list Keycloak users in a table go with frontend as it is faster to implement. If you need to hide some sensitive user data or do not want to give frontend users access to Keycloak API go with backend.

Also be aware that through the API you can do anything the same as through the admin console. Users of your frontend application can get access that they should not have.

As an example, in Keycloak admin console, all requests from the frontend are sent directly to the API.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice in my opinion is:

Create a **CMS**, **Database** or **API-endpoint** where to query the data from in your front-end.

This will only query data when needed.